# YouTube Custom Brand on iPhone

Tags: iphone, iframe, youtube, youtube-channels

I am having a hard time trying to fit a YouTube custom brand channel on an iPhone.

It's just a simple html page, and it fits well outside YouTube - the page is 640px wide and I use the viewport meta tag to make it fit well, this works fine outside the youtube structure.

On youtube the content gets bigger than the iPhone viewport, it seems like it shows only 320px, YouTube defines the viewport to equal device-width, so it may be the cause. Any ideas about how make it fit well on youtube channel?